# Laravel redirect after Auth::logout() not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, routes, inertiajs

I want to logout and redirect the user from `/admin/home` to `/` url. According to [docs on logging out](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#logging-out) it should work like so:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::logout();
 
    $request->session()->invalidate();
 
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
 
    return redirect('/');
}
```

The logout works but the `redirect` doesn't. The url just stays `/admin/home`.

The `logout route` is at the bottom of `auth` middleware in **`web.php`**:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function() {

        Route::inertia('/home', 'home')->name('admin.home');
        Route::inertia('/events', 'events')->name('admin.events');
        Route::inertia('/event-view', 'event-view')->name('admin.event-view');
        Route::inertia('/gallery', 'gallery')->name('admin.gallery');
        Route::inertia('/gallery-view', 'gallery-view')->name('admin.gallery-view');
        Route::inertia('/news', 'news')->name('admin.news');
        Route::inertia('/news-view', 'news-view')->name('admin.news-view');
        Route::inertia('/service', 'service')->name('admin.service');
        Route::inertia('/contact', 'contact')->name('admin.contact');

        Route::get('/terms', [LegalPageController::class, 'indexTerms'])->name('admin.terms');
        Route::put('/terms/update', [LegalPageController::class, 'updateTerms'])->name('admin.terms.update');
        Route::get('/privacy', [LegalPageController::class, 'indexPrivacy'])->name('admin.privacy');
        Route::put('/privacy/update', [LegalPageController::class, 'updatePrivacy'])->name('admin.privacy.update');
        Route::get('/copyright', [LegalPageController::class, 'indexCopyright'])->name('admin.copyright');
        Route::put('/copyright/update', [LegalPageController::class, 'updateCopyright'])->name('admin.copyright.update');
        Route::get('/disclaimer', [LegalPageController::class, 'indexDisclaimer'])->name('admin.disclaimer');
        Route::put('/disclaimer/update', [LegalPageController::class, 'updateDisclaimer'])->name('admin.disclaimer.update');
        Route::get('/legal', [LegalPageController::class, 'indexLegal'])->name('admin.legal');
        Route::put('/legal/update', [LegalPageController::class, 'updateLegal'])->name('admin.legal.update');
        Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'indexAbout'])->name('admin.about');
        Route::put('/about/update', [AboutController::class, 'updateAbout'])->name('admin.about.update');

        Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);
        Route::any('/{any}', function () {
            Route::inertia('/', 'home')->name('admin.home');
        });
});
```

The route is fed from the frontend like so:

```
const logout = () => {
    axios.post('/admin/logout')
}
```

In case this is relevant:

1. I don't use `remember_token` in my `users` database.
2. `Request` is an empty array because I don't know which data to pass in from the frontend.

Comment: Please share `route for '/'` you are redirecting. As you shared routes are in `Auth` middleware.

Comment: @WaqasAltaf `Route::inertia('/', 'home')->name('home');`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new logout logic for example like this:
add below shown code to the: `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

```
protected function loggedOut(Request $request) {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: I've tried putting this function in the controller and triggering it from the `logout()` function but the redirect is still not working. I could trigger it from the frontend after the `logout()` has been processed but it would be even easier to trigger a redirect in the frontend with `window.location.href = '/'` in the response function of `axios`.

Comment: Add it to: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

Comment: Please try it. I'm not sure.

Comment: I was wrong, it was in `Auth` folder. Calling the function after `Auth::logout()` doesn't work.

Comment: https://lavalite.org/blog/redirect-to-a-page-after-logging-out-in-laravel

Comment: I'm so sorry if i couldn't help you.